# Print.css issue in Webkit

Tags: css, webkit, printing

The page in question is featured here: http://www.allwebcafe.com/news/news-article.php?id=78

For some reason, when a user attempts to print any article of this type from a Webkit-based browser (I've confirmed this in both Safari and Chrome), the pages are all blank. On the flip side, everything behaves as expected in both Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Thoughts?

Comment: What version are we speaking of? Safari version 4.0.5 (6531.22.7) on OS X 10.6.2 works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this way a cache issue where my browser was referencing an earlier version of the same print.css stylesheet.  All is working now.